# Angular validation is not working in bootstrap modal popup

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular8

**I have form and and that form is opening is bootstrap modal popup but angular validations is not working in that modal popup.**

[image]

Thank in advance

Comment: what is the error an occur

Comment: validation is not fired

Comment: Please share your code or create a demo.

Comment: How to create demo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the validation code snippet and for deeply info you can check the attached link:

```
this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]]
});
```

https://therichpost.com/angular-8-bootstrap-popup-login-form/

Thank you